# Can't find Tomlin in Dragon's Dogma

Tags: dragons-dogma

I'm running around Cassardis looking for [Tomlin](http://dragonsdogma.wikia.com/wiki/Tomlin) for the [An Innocent Man](http://dragonsdogma.wikia.com/wiki/An_Innocent_Man) quest. However, Tomlin just can't be found - **anywhere**!

---

I've run around for about an hour and checked every single building, slept twice to see if he's around at night, but the little bugger just doesn't want to be found!

I fulfil all the prerequisites for the quest, I'm pretty sure he hasn't been killed, and this being my second play through means I need to find him for that damned achievement.

Any suggestions on where I might find him?

---

Points of interest that I've checked:

- The stairs north of the beach
- The chapel
- The chieftains house

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, he wasn't here every other time we checked, however he was in **Chief Adaro's** hut; but not standing up where you'd expect him to be. This is why we missed him:

[image: Absolute lazy git was lying down, we just ran right past him!]

So basically, when you're running around and looking, check he's not passed out on the floor like he was here.